# How to wait for function (with no callback) to run in Jquery before exceuting next statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, parse-platform

I am using the service Parse to write a user authentication system. Parse provides a Logout function which logs out the current user, but that function does not provide a callback option.

My dilemma is that I need to run a function after the asynchronous logout function has been completed. How can that be accomplished without modifying the Parse framework?

Here is my code:

```
function logOut() {

    if (getCurrentUsername()) {

    Parse.User.logOut();

    // Need this to wait till the logOut function completes
    loggedIn();

    } else {

    }

}

function loggedIn() {

 if (getCurrentUsername()) {
    //Hide the sign in form because it is not needed
    $('#sign_in_form').hide();

    //Get the username of the current user by calling the function getCurrentUsername()
    var currentUsername = getCurrentUsername();

    //Write a welcome message to the current user and give a log out option
    $('#signed_in_note').html('Welcome <a href="#">'+ currentUsername +'</a> | <a href="#" id="log_out">log out</a>')

    //Show the welcome message
    $('#signed_in_note').show();

 } else {

 //If no user is signed in, we show the login form and hide the welcome message
  $('#sign_in_form').show();
  $('#signed_in_note').hide();
 }
}
```

Comment: That's totally impossible.  Are you _sure_ that it doesn't accept a callback or return a promise?

Comment: You could tie up the browser with a `while (true) {}` but most modern browsers will detect that and prompt you to kill the script.

Comment: It doesn't offer this : https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html#.logOut But I don't get why you would need to wait for the operation to be done server side.

Comment: the function doesnt seem async , except for the FB api call, maybe you can can a FB event directly , the rest doesnt seem to be async.

Comment: @Lloyd: That won't work anyway.

Comment: @SLaks Why not? I'd assume it'd jam everything including processing callbacks etc?

Comment: @Lloyd: Exactly.  It will freeze forever, with no way to know when to stop.

Comment: I didn't mean that literally, I meant more `while (true) { if (terminate) break; }`.

Comment: @Lloyd: But the callback cannot run until no other code is running, so `terminate` will never change.  Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: @SLaks Yeh that's what I figured would end up happening.

Comment: @dystroy - I am attempting to hide the "welcome user" and show the login box upon successful logout, therefore I need a way to know when the logout function has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a simple timer to check if the user is still authenticated:

```
var currentUser;
var timerId;

function logOut() {
    currentUser = getCurrentUsername();
    if (currentUser) {
      Parse.User.logOut();
      timerId = setInterval(checkAuth, 200);
    } else {
      //show msg saying already logged out or log an error
    }

}

function checkAuth() {
    // check if user is logged out
    if(!currentUser.authenticated()) {
      abortTimer();
      loggedIn();    //now this will run only after user is logged out
    }
}

function abortTimer() { 
  clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

P.S: Don't rely on this to work in 100% cases since user might close the browser before logout call returns.